# Using Backbone.js with wordpress causes problems?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, backbone.js

I'm on a wordpress plugin project that borrows some wordpress media features.

I need to use backbone to build the plugin, but as wordpress media uses backbone too, I'm afraid this will cause a problem because wordpress uses different version of backbone.

I don't blame wordpress, but I've learnt `wp.media` source code (too bad, there's no documentation) and found out that they still uses old version of backbone (still uses controller, this.options, etc).

I don't want to write old backbone version. So I have some ideas in my mind:

1. Register the latest version of backbone and have duplicate script in the end.
2. Deregister wordpress' backbone and register a new one, with possibility some wordpress features will not work.
3. Just write script and pray wordpress' backbone will make it works.

I still don't know exactly which version of backbone that wordpress uses. If there's another way my backbone plugin can work without bothering wordpress features, please tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone has a `noConflict` mode described [here](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-14)

> Runs Backbone.js in noConflict mode, returning the Backbone variable to its previous owner. Returns a reference to this Backbone object.

If you load "your" Backbone after the Wordpress one. Then calling `Backbone.noConflict()` should restore the Wordpress version so `window.Backbone` points at the one they're using and you can use the reference it returns to declare yours as `window.MyBackbone` or whatever else you fancy.

It's not exactly pretty, but I think that's your best option.

Comment: Will Backbone.noconflict change the way I write the script then? So how to use both `window.Backbone` and `window.MyBackbone`?

Comment: @Pius The old Wordpress could would still use `window.Backbone`, no need to touch that as long as you call `noConflict` before it starts setting up its models, views and collections. Your new code would need to use `window.MyBackbone` which is the not pretty part.

Comment: I think it's more about compability problem. Say I want a router, I write `router` in my plugin. It just doesnt work because the backbone version not yet supports `router`, but `controller`. And if I include the latest version of backbone, it will override the wordpress version and wp features who still use `controller` won't work.